# Can I push myself away from me?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, grapple, forced-movement

In their extensive comments on [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/72006/23547), V2Blast explains that including yourself in the area of effect of a *[thunderwave](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thunderwave)* is possible, but asks, perhaps rhetorically, why one would ever want to.

Some immediate uses that spring to mind are a low-strength caster using it to escape the effects of a grapple, *entangle*, *web*, or any situation where forced movement would be helpful.

Regardless of *why* one might want to do it, however, the question remains - if one targets oneself with *thunderwave* or other forced movement spell, can one be moved?  *Thunderwave* says

> On a failed save, a creature takes 2d8 thunder damage and is pushed 10 feet away from you.

The question for me is, **can you be moved 'away from you' and if so, what direction would that be?**

[This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/112732/23547) to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/112714/23547) somewhat blithely assumes that you can, but does not explain why or what direction that would be.

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate as it has been asked before, and answered by yours truly.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Thank you - my search on "move away from you" did not turn that up.  I agree that on the surface it is a duplicate.  The actual answer, I think is different, though, but explaining why will require I answer _that_ question, so it goes on the to do list.

Comment: You may find the [4e equivalent of this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/22546/3548) of interest.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I saw that as I was searching to see whether this question had been asked for 5e, but haven't read it yet.  Thank you for the link.